# How to send AWS CodeBuild's test result to slack

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

How can I send AWS Code Build test report to slack channel??

I'm trying to build CI pipeline, using by AWS services for rails app. and have found AWS code build and Chat bot.

Ideally I want to send failed test case name to slack channel, but i can only  send building status. I'm pretty new to AWS ,Is there any good way to send notification to slack?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I got it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the build in notifications of CodeBuild (CB) or CodePipepline (CP), don't suite you, you can always add extra code to your CB `buildspec.yml` to send the **custom notifications** and messages to your slack.

Or create a lambda function which triggers when your CB fails. The lambda would pick up more details and send it to your slack.